# WPF Material Design Button Hover

Tags: c#, wpf, button, material-design

I am using the [Material Design](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit) for my WPF Project and I now want to set a background color for the hover state of a button.
As seen in the code, the implementation is made with a ProgressBar, Ripple and Border.

If I try to overwrite the style, i end up having a invisible Button:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignRaisedButton}">
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="{StaticResource MainColorSolidBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground"
            Value="{StaticResource TextColorLightSolidBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                    <!--Hover-->
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                             Value="true">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                    To="{StaticResource SubColor}"
                                                    FillBehavior="HoldEnd"
                                                    Duration="{StaticResource HoverStartDuration}" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                    To="{StaticResource MainColor}"
                                                    FillBehavior="Stop"
                                                    Duration="{StaticResource HoverEndDuration}" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                    </Trigger>

                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

So do I have to reimplement the original style from the package and add a Hover?

Comment: Okay, so I need to reimplement the whole RaisedButton and add the hover effect manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot "override" only a part of a template. It has to be defined as a whole which means that you should copy the `MaterialDesignRaisedButton` style from [GitHub](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/4108abe301116e59dcbacd3c26fc252615e8de28/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Button.xaml) and edit it as per your requirements, by for example adding additional setters to the `IsMouseOver` trigger.